# I Can't Stop Haskell From Listing Numbers

Tags: haskell

My question is simple.  I told Haskell b = [1..].  I then typed b.  Now Haskell is listing all the natural numbers.  How do I stop it from doing that?

Comment: You want to stop it from doing what you told him? Or you just want a way to terminate the execution? In that way, CTRL+C should suffice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends on the environment you're using, but try control-C. That should send an interrupt signal to GHCi. If you want to just get a certain number of elements from a list, you can use the `take` function: `take 10 [1..]`.

Comment: Thank you much.  I will accept the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: I'm new to programming.  I just wanted to see what would happen.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126: That's a great attitude to have. Keep trying stuff out!

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 I envy you. I wish I had started programming with Haskell.